# Quicksort Python sorting trouble

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
def quicksort(mas):
    if mas:
        mid = mas[0]
        menshe = [i for i in mas[1:] if i < mid]
        bolshe = [i for i in mas[1:] if i >= mid]
        return quicksort(menshe) + [mid] + quicksort(bolshe)
    else: 
        return mas

n = int(input())
mas = input().split()
print(*quicksort(mas))
```

It fails on some tests, for example

```
input:
3
8 21 22
output:
21 22 8
```

how to improve the code?

Comment: Your input `mas` contains strings, not integers. Therefore you have a lexicographic sort: `2` is before `8`.

Comment: Note: your `n` variable is unused. Maybe `mas = input().split()[:n]`? Or `mas = [int(item) for item in input().split()[:n]]` to also include the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may very well work. I've yet to test it. (but now that I have it seems correct)

Your mistake is that you discard your first input. So, you should use your own code like this:

```
mas = input().split()
print(*quicksort(mas))
```

You only need one input.

Also, you are sorting strings, not necessarily numbers, so you *may* want to do this:

```
mas = input().split()
print(*quicksort([int(item) for item in mas]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your quicksort implementation seems to be correct, but you forgot to convert your input to integers. You are sorting strings.

As a side note: don't forget that pivot selection strategy is very important in quicksort algorithm. Your "first element as a pivot" scheme is similar to [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) that easily degrades to `O(n^2)` for ordered or almost ordered sequences.